# How to view created JSON string using Retrofit

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

I am not sure if this is a silly question (hence why I am unable to find the answer) but I was wondering if it is possible to Toast or Log output the created JSON that is being sent to the server, when it is sent.

I am simply interested to see the created JSON - I am using the following method, which is using `Retrofit` and `.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))`:

```
private void addTeamMember(final List teamMemberArray,final String team_id) {

    //helps with debugging regarding post requests
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();


    //Retrofit is a REST Client for Android and Java by Square.
    //It makes it relatively easy to retrieve and upload JSON (or other structured data) via a REST based webservice
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            //directing to the localhost which is defined in the Constants Class as BASE_URL
            .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
            //Add converter factory for serialization and deserialization of objects.
            //Gson passed as a parameter to help with debug
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            //Create the Retrofit instance using the configured values.
            .build();



    //The Retrofit class generates an implementation of the RequestInterface interface.
    RequestInterface requestInterface = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);



    for (Object x : teamMemberArray) {


        //create new Team object
        TeamMember teamMember = new TeamMember();


        //setter
        teamMember.setFullName(String.valueOf(x));
        teamMember.setTeam_id(team_id);

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), teamMember.getFullName(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        //create new server object
        final ServerRequest request = new ServerRequest();


        //make a request to set the operation to Team_Member
        request.setOperation(Constants.Team_Member);
        //set values entered for the new teamMember to be sent to the server
        request.setTeamMember(teamMember);


        Call<ServerResponse> response = requestInterface.operation(request);


        /**
         * Enqueue is used to Asynchronously send the request and notify callback of its response or if an error occurred
         * talking to the server, creating the request, or processing the response.
         */


        response.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<ServerResponse> response) {

                ServerResponse resp = response.body();


            /*Snackbars provide lightweight feedback about an operation. They show a brief message at the
            bottom of the screen on mobile and lower left on larger devices. Snackbars appear above all other
            elements on screen and only one can be displayed at a time.
             */


                Snackbar.make(getView(), resp.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                if (resp.getResult().equals(Constants.SUCCESS)) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();


                    Log.d("TEST VALUE", "getTeamMemberName() = " + response.body().getTeamMember().getFullName() );
                    Log.d("TEST VALUE", "getTeamMemberUniqueID() = " + response.body().getTeamMember().getUnique_id());
                    Log.d("TEST VALUE", "getTeamMemberTeamID() = " + response.body().getTeamMember().getTeamID());

                          editor.putString(Constants.FULL_NAME, resp.getTeamMember().getFullName());
                          editor.putString(Constants.UNIQUE_ID, resp.getTeamMember().getUnique_id());
                          editor.putString(Constants.TEAM_ID, resp.getTeamMember().getTeamID());
                          editor.apply();
                          goToQuestions();

                }

                progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Log.d(Constants.TAG, "failed" + t);
                Snackbar.make(getView(), t.getLocalizedMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
        });
    }

}
```

My reasoning is that if I could see the JSON being sent across, it will help me with debugging when using Postman.

Comment: What u want exactly  and which version of retrofit you are using

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `OkHttpInterceptor` for logging network calls with `Retrofit`. It will intercept any call and show logs in logger.

Add dependecy in your gradle:

```
 compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
```

Then before setting your retrofit client use:

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
logging.setLevel(Level.BASIC);
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
  .addInterceptor(logging)
  .build();
```

And finally add in retrofit:

```
 retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this in `dependencies`

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
```

and ApiClient

```
    public class ApiClient {


    public static final String BASE_URL = "URL";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;



    public static Retrofit getClient() {

        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);


        final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .readTimeout(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .addInterceptor(logging)
                .build();


        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }

}
```